# c# WPF if statement for a check box and button press

Tags: c#, wpf

Im looking to write an if statement for when a checkbox is checked and a button is pressed then do something however i can't get the if statement to work.

This is the code i have so far

```
 if (GPBox.IsChecked == true  && SearchButton.MouseUp == true )
        {
            connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            cmd = new MySqlCommand("select distinct * from gpSurgery", connect);
            connect.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            connect.Close();
            DataGrid1.DataContext = dt;
        }
```

Comment: "*button is pressed*" means you want to do this in a Button Click event handler (and there only check if the CheckBox is checked). Your code won't compile because `MouseUp` is not a boolean property, but an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you not change it instead of the  `MouseUp` to the Button_Click

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (GPBox.IsChecked == true)
     {
         connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
         cmd = new MySqlCommand("select distinct * from gpSurgery", connect);
         connect.Open();
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
         connect.Close();
         DataGrid1.DataContext = dt;
      }
}
```

My testing code
XAML

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox x:Name="GPBox"/>
    <Button Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (GPBox.IsChecked == true)
        MessageBox.Show("222");
}
```

I hope it is enough to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

That code should go on to MouseUp event of the button, and then you don't need

```
&& SearchButton.MouseUp == true
```

You could add the mouseup event in xaml where your button is.

In the event handler you would write:

```
 if (GPBox.IsChecked == true)
    {
        connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        cmd = new MySqlCommand("select distinct * from gpSurgery", connect);
        connect.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        connect.Close();
        DataGrid1.DataContext = dt;
    }
```

Comment: This worked thank you ill accept as an answer when i can